# Flexbox column-reverse in Firefox, Edge and IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox, flexbox

I'm trying to make a responsive app; on larger screens, there's a list of divs and you can scroll *up* to see previous divs ("traditional" behavior). On smaller screens, it shows the same list but reverses the order, so scrolling *down* sees shows divs.

I figured flexbox would be an awesome solution to this, and it was... on Chrome.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="list">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="item">9</div>
</div>
```

And, the CSS:

```
#list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  height: 250px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.item {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 2em;
  border: 1px dashed green;
}
```

As well as a fiddle to show it: http://jsfiddle.net/jbkmy4dc/3/

In Chrome, the `list` div properly shows a scroll bar. However, in Firefox and in IE/Edge, the scroll bar is visible but disabled.

Any ideas? Am I missing a vendor prefix maybe?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As a workaround, you can distribute the styles of your container among two different containers:

- The outer one with the sizes, borders and overflow
- The inner one with the flexbox styles

If you want it to be scrolled to the bottom by default, you can use JS: [Scroll to bottom of div?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/270612/1529630)

```js
function scrollToBottom(el) { el.scrollTop = el.scrollHeight; }
scrollToBottom(document.getElementById('list'));
```

```css
#list {
  height: 250px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#inner-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
.item {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 2em;
  border: 1px dashed green;
}
```

```html
<div id="list">
  <div id="inner-list">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
    <div class="item">6</div>
    <div class="item">7</div>
    <div class="item">8</div>
    <div class="item">9</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: in chrome I see only 3 2 1 and no scrollbar

Comment: @rofrol Chrome needed `flex-shrink: 0` on `#inner`. I have updated the answer, thanks.

Comment: @rofol Or even better, there was no need to make the outer container a flex container.

Answer (score 20):

This is a bug in Firefox, Edge and IE11.

With `flex-direction: column-reverse` the scroll bar appears only in Chrome.

If you switch to `column` the scroll bar works on all browsers.

More information:

- [Bug 1042151 - flex-direction: column-reverse (or "flex-direction:column; justify-content:flex-end") with overflow-y: auto is not scrollable](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1042151)
- [Philip Walton / flexbugs - Column-reverse and overflow-y not scrollable](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs/issues/108)

Comment: Oh cool, looks like the working group has accepted a definition that will fix this... I guess I'll keep using it for now and hope that vendors can agree on some functionality ;)

Comment: This bug was fixed in FF 81 released on September 2020. Edge is now based on Chromium so it's also working there.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1042151) in firefox and is logged in bugzilla.
Please vote up [this bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1042151).

They are considering fixing it this years(only 6 years after bug was opened)

Comment: 7 years on, I face this issue. Any update on this?

Comment: I believe this is fixed in > Firefox 81

Answer (score 1):

Since this firefox-bug is still in place: note that under the second link
provided in the [answer by Michael_B](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34251527/6879357), kumarharsh gives two css-only "whacky
workaround[s]"  that have the scroll-down
behaviour as in chrome. From  [kumarharsh's post](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs/issues/108#issuecomment-396908863) on [philipwalton list of flexbugs](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs):

> Till then, here's some whacky workaround with 2 transforms: http://jsfiddle.net/RedDevil/qar7Lc5s/ (rotate transforms) or http://jsfiddle.net/RedDevil/0z5t6j9m/ (scale transforms - better IMO)

Disadvantages: the solutions use `transform` and in firefox the content
loses sharpness when scrolling. Also the scrolling behaviour is upside down, or
the scrollbar on the wrong side.

Comment: Is there a possibility, to make scroll behavior not to be upside down with this solution?