# webkit-overflow-scrolling conflicting with css transform

Tags: css, transform, flexbox

I'm having a serious issue here trying to develop a hybrid application on iOS. The problem is that I use `flex-direction: column-reverse` in order to show replies in a message. Everything works fine but I need the `translate3d` or `translateZ` hack to get the replies updated when an event is received. Anyway, I do that, everythings fine as well but.. when I enable the `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch`, the content goes crazy. Everything's fine but the content is positioned wrong. If I change `flex-direction: column-reverse` to `flex-direction: column` everything is fine, but then I want the order in the exact other way ( and this way I benefit from the "always bottom" positioning when new message is received as well ).

If you have an iOS device, please check http://edi.srl/ios.html :: it's easier to see here than on jsfiddle. Go on landscape orientation and see what happens with the positioning of the "replies".

1. If I switch `flex-direction: column-reverse` to `column`, everything is ok but then the layout is not how I want it.
2. If I remove the `translate3d` or `translateZ` option, everything is ok as well, but the updates are not rendering ( unless I scroll the elements out of the viewport so they can get re-rendered ).
3. If I remove `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch`, again, everything is fine, but then the scroll would be really really weird to deal with as you probably know.

Any ideas ?

Comment: possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34249501/3597276