# Flexbox column-reverse disabling animations on iOS

Tags: ios, css, debugging, animation, flexbox

Attempting to use `flex-direction: column-reverse` to reverse items in a list and also start the scrollbar at the bottom. This works okay on Chrome/Safari (with the exception of `padding-top` not working as expected).

Anyhow, if you view this on an iOS device, you won't see anything. Animations and transitions are not working with `flex-direction: column-reverse`. If you change this to `flex-direction: column` everything works as expected. And there's something with `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch` not playing nice with `column-reverse` as well.

You can also see that `padding-top` is not being respected.

Example:
http://codepen.io/ryanmclaughlin/pen/cad31489bf2dcc4d2b03a88fdd649ecf/

Comment: possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34249501/3597276