# Why on toggling flex-direction item with lowest order gets scrolled into the viewport?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have a list done with **CSS FlexBox**. I have assigned by some criteria `order` to all flexbox **items**, so the list is visually sorted. Also I have a button that toggles `flex-direction` of flexbox **container**, so I can revert the presentation order. I have limited space, so using `overflow-y: scroll;` and when I'm reverting visual order of the list with `flex-direction`, element with `order: 1` is being scrolled into the viewport. So when it's on top (`flex-direction: column;`) - scroll in the the beginning of container (there are 10 items in the list),

[image]

but when I apply `flex-direction: column-reverse;` - I can still see this element, but now scroll is in the bottom of container:

[image]

**Why is the scroll following the element with lowest `order` property?**

Here is my code in [Relative codepen](https://codepen.io/ichyr/pen/eKWzJo) or inlined below

**HTML**

```
<div class="alternator">
  <button>Reverse order</button>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item a10">10 away</div>
  <div class="item a2">2 upon</div>
  <div class="item a3">3 a</div>
  <div class="item a4">4 time</div>
  <div class="item a5">5 in</div>
  <div class="item a6">6 a</div>
  <div class="item a7">7 galaxy</div>
  <div class="item a1">1 once</div>
  <div class="item a8">8 very</div>
  <div class="item a9">9 far</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-height: 350px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  width: 150px;
}

.wrapper.reversed {
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

.item {
  height: 30px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.a1{order: 1;}
.a2{order: 2;}
.a3{order: 3;}
.a4{order: 4;}
.a5{order: 5;}
.a6{order: 6;}
.a7{order: 7;}
.a8{order: 8;}
.a9{order: 9;}
.a10{order: 10;}

button {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

**JS**

```
const btn = document.querySelector('.alternator button');
const list = document.querySelector('.wrapper');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  list.classList.toggle('reversed');
})
```

**UPDATE** As answer below deals with scrolling side, I must add here that `flex-direction: *-reverse` works like `order` property - namely only visually changes the order of elements, so first element in DOM tree remains there after rendering:

> “Note: The reordering capabilities of flex layout intentionally affect
>   only the visual rendering, leaving speech order and navigation based
>   on the source order. This allows authors to manipulate the visual
>   presentation while leaving the source order intact for non-CSS UAs and
>   for linear models such as speech and sequential navigation.” -
>   [Ordering and Orientation](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flow-order)

[Reference from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items).

Comment: I don't think the problem is related to the `order` property. I believe it's related to the `column-reverse` value. Are you aware that the vertical scrollbar itself, in `column-reverse`, doesn't work in Firefox and IE? Check your code in those browsers. Also see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34249501/3597276

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why exactly this is, but I'm thinking it has to do with that the scroll works in that way - it starts out at the first element in the DOM.

According to MDN concerning the target of scroll (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll):

> The event target (the topmost target in the DOM tree).

But here's a little hack that might fix it:

add item 0 to the top of the list `<div class="item a0">000</div>` and then do the following:

```
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    list.classList.toggle('reversed');
    if(list.classList.contains('reversed') ){
        list.children[0].style.order = 100;
    } else {
        list.children[0].style.order = 0;
    }
    list.children[0].scrollIntoView();
});
```

Comment: hi, @Winter. Can you please point me where this is written in documentation or some good article: `scroll works in that way - it starts out at the first element in the DOM.` ?

Comment: Well, I found a little hint in the MDN documentation on scroll. I have updated my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use an extra div inside the (scrollable) wrapper as the flexbox container.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">    <-- scrollable
    <div>                <-- flexbox container
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        ...
        <div></div>
    <div>
<div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-height: 350px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  width: 150px;
}
.wrapper > div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.wrapper.reversed > div {
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

[CodePen example](https://codepen.io/torp/pen/yLYgWqq)