# Make a list of text stay above footer but able to scroll them underneath the compose bar

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to scroll a list of messages so that it goes below the compose bar yet when new messages are added they should be added just above the compose bar. For a quick demo of what I mean, see the image in this [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4pyq7FDc_byVnJXU21IQlZTZ28).

**My Problems:**

- I am not being able to control the width of the elements of inner div according to its content size.
- Not being able to get the desired scroll(as in the image) properly

```css
.contentContainer {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 68px;
  height: calc(100vh - 68px);
  display: block;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  height: inherit;
}

.messageArea {
  flex-grow: 1;
  /*min-width: 400px;*/
  height: inherit;
  position: relative;
}

.scrollingMessagesList {
  height: inherit;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  transform: translateZ(0);
}

.outer {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 142px;
  height: 414px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #78909c;
}

.inner {
  margin: 0 20px;
  height: inherit;
  background-color: darkkhaki;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.inner p {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  outline: none;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  background-color: greenyellow;
}

.composeBar {
  z-index: 1029!important;
  border: none;
  bottom: 20px;
}

.compose {
  height: 52px;
  border-radius: 26px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .16), 0 4px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .10), 0 3px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .08);
  ;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid contentContainer" style="background-color: blanchedalmond;">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="messageArea">
      <div class="scrollingMessagesList">
        <div class="outer">
          <div class="inner">
            <p>Text 1</p>
            <p>Text 2</p>
            <p>Text 3</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="composeBar navbar-fixed-bottom">
        <div class="compose">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have a look at my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34213227/scrollable-div-to-stick-to-bottom-when-outer-div-changes-in-size/34330934#34330934

Comment: @LGSon, am not sure how to implement it. Although I updated the code and now using flex-direction: reverse I get my threads in reverse order. For ex: Text 1 and Text 2 is shown as Text 2 and Text 1.

Comment: I see you got help :)

Comment: @LGSon, I could use some help of yours too, if you don't mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, you can check i have updated your code, Please review if found helpful.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function setHeight() {
    windowHeight = $(window).outerHeight();
    $('.inner').css('min-height', windowHeight - 68);
  };
  setHeight();
  
  $(window).resize(function() {
    setHeight();
  });
});
```

```css
.contentContainer {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  overflow-y: auto;
  margin-top: 68px;
  height: calc(100vh - 68px);
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  height: inherit;
}

.messageArea {
  flex-grow: 1;
  /*min-width: 400px;*/
  height: inherit;
  position: relative;
}

.scrollingMessagesList {
  height: inherit;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  transform: translateZ(0);
}

.outer {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #78909c;
}

.inner {
  margin: 0 20px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: darkkhaki;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.inner p {  
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  outline: none;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  background-color: greenyellow;
  
}

.composeBar {
  z-index: 1029!important;
  border: none;
  bottom: 5px !important;
  position: fixed;
}


.compose {
    height: 52px;
    border-radius: 26px;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .16), 0 4px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .10), 0 3px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .08);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid contentContainer" style="background-color: blanchedalmond;">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="messageArea">
      <div class="scrollingMessagesList">
        <div class="outer">
          <div class="inner">
            <p>Text 1</p>
            <p>Text 2</p>
            <p>Text 3</p>
            <p>Text 4</p>
            <p>Text 5</p>
            <p>Text 6</p>
            <p>Text 7</p>
           <p>Text 7</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>    
      <div class="composeBar navbar-fixed-bottom">
         <div class="compose">
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What if there is no elements then the div will be squeezed, then?

Comment: On further testing I found that if there are no elements in the inner div and suddenly a new element is added to it then that element is showed at the top of the inner div whereas it should be few pixels above the compose bar.

Comment: I have updated my code, have a look. The problem is when the page loads and if the list is long, the list goes below the compose bar. Take a minute look at the image in my question.

Comment: Hello @ayan i think we need to fix the min height of inner div using jquery , in case there is a long converstaion it will increase automatically. What do you think

Comment: Hoping so. But then when the conversation increases the overflow will increase towards bottom hence expanding the message list below the compose div, again not what I want. The overflow should be towards the top so that only when I scroll the list should freely move up and down the vieport height. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, That is what i am doing

Comment: @Ayan, check this out i have set min-height according to window height . Check the updated code please. Let me know if any help required

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153757/discussion-between-anmol-sandal-and-ayan).