# Scroll to bottom when new message added

Tags: javascript, html, css, parceljs

I am making a chatbot. I want to scroll to the bottom of the chat box when a new input is given by the user or the Data is sent through API.

It doesn't scroll and scroll just stays in the same position but the data is being added in the chat box

I Have tried the code from other chat bot but it didn't work either

```js
var outputArea = $('#chat-output');
$('#user-input-form').on('submit', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var message = $('#user-input').val();

  outputArea.append(`
    <div class='bot-message'>
      <div class='message'>
        ${message}
      </div>
    </div>
  `);



  const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', (d) => {
      const myobj = JSON.parse(d);
      if ('narrative' in myobj.conversationalResponse.responses[0]) {
        const temp = myobj.conversationalResponse.responses[0].narrative.text;
        outputArea.append(`
      <div class='user-message'>
        <div class='message'>
          ${temp}
        </div>
      </div>
    `);
      } else if ('imageUrl' in myobj.conversationalResponse.responses[0]) {
        const img = myobj.conversationalResponse.responses[0].imageUrl;
        if ('narrative' in myobj.conversationalResponse.responses[1]) {
          const text_r = myobj.conversationalResponse.responses[1].narrative.text;
          outputArea.append(`
      <div class='user-message'>
      <div class ="message">
      ${text_r}
      <a href=""></a>
      </div>
      </div>
    `);
        } else {
          outputArea.append(`
      <div class='user-message'>
        <div class='message'>
         <img src="" width="300" height="200">
        </div>
      </div>
    `);
        }
      }
    });
  });

  req.on('error', (error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });

  req.write(data);
  req.end();

  $('#user-input').val('');
```

```css
.form-container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 450px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: scroll;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="chat-popup" id="myForm">
<div class="form-container">

  <div class="chat-output" id="chat-output">
    <div class="user-message">
      <div class="message">Hi! I'm Bot, what's up?</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="chat-input">
    <form action="#0" id="user-input-form" autocomplete="off">
      <input type="text" id="user-input" class="user-input" placeholder="Talk to the bot.">
    </form>
  </div>
  </br></br>
  <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm()">Close</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: where did you determine that the screen should scroll down?

Comment: scroll the container after a new message is appended. `outputArea[0].scrollTop = 9e9;` If `outputArea` is not the container, adjust that selector to point to the container, trying each parent all the way to `document.documentElement`; somewhere along the chain it will scroll...

Comment: thanks  the outputArea[0].scrollTop = 9e9; worked for me :D

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
outputArea[0].scrollTop = 9e9;
```

Answer (score 42):

Another interesting method is by using pure CSS, using the `flex-direction` method, which works by creating a wrapper for the content *inside* the scrolling element.

I've whipped up a quick demo below (with a button and some JavaScript for adding new items). You can also check out [this separate demo-page](https://code.hnldesign.nl/scrolltobottom/).

The trick then lies in reversing the content direction using `column-reverse` in the scroller. Because the items are in another container, they don't get 'flipped' but instead always line up to the bottom. This, in fact, makes the scroller scrolled to the bottom whenever stuff is added.

[image: Breakdown, click for demo]

##### Added bonus: keeps scroll position (mostly*)

Also, and this is something I really like about the method; whenever the user has started scrolling (up), the scroller will not lose its scroll position when stuff is being added. So, it will only 'stick' tot the bottom if it was already scrolled (by default, or by the user) to the bottom. This makes sure there's no annoying content jumping, offering a better user experience.

* Mostly, because only iOS Safari doesn't support `overflow-anchor`, so it will always keep scrolling the container, regardless of user scroll position. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-anchor#browser_compatibility

### Demo

Note: the JavaScript is only because of demonstration-purposes: the solution itself is purely CSS-based.

```js
let scrollerContent = document.getElementById('scrollerContent');

document.getElementById('addItems').addEventListener('click', function() {
  let newChild = scrollerContent.lastElementChild.cloneNode(true);
  newChild.innerHTML = "Item " + (scrollerContent.children.length + 1);
  scrollerContent.appendChild(newChild);
});
```

```css
.scroller {
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    overflow-anchor: auto !important; /*  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-anchor */
}

.scroller .scroller-content .item {
    height: 20px;
    transform: translateZ(0); /* fixes a bug in Safari iOS where the scroller doesn't update */
}
```

```html
<div class="scroller">
  <div class="scroller-content" id="scrollerContent">
    <div class="item">Item 1</div>
    <div class="item">Item 2</div>
    <div class="item">Item 3</div>
    <div class="item">Item 4</div>
    <div class="item">Item 5</div>
    <div class="item">Item 6</div>
    <div class="item">Item 7</div>
    <div class="item">Item 8</div>
    <div class="item">Item 9</div>
    <div class="item">Item 10</div>
  </div>
</div>
<br/><br/>
<button id="addItems">Add more items</button>
```

Comment: Although I implemented it with scrollTop, I also like the pure CSS way, it's interesting

Comment: I discovered this method last year, and I really like how clean and simple (and JS independent) it is

Comment: Awesome solution! A lot of unnecessary code left my project. You made my day :D

Comment: This in my humble opinion should be the accepted answer.

Comment: An interesting approach! Thank you, @KlaasLeussink

Comment: I love this, but on iOS Safari it looks like when you add a new element to the list while you're scrolling in the middle, the list moves

Comment: @ChristopherDemicoli yes, that's something I can't get my head around. As you can see, I use a 'trick' to place the scroll items into the 3D layer @ Safari. This takes the middle ground, as it makes the list update when it's scrollled to the bottom, which is probably what you want anyway. You can work around this by updating the `scrollTop` of the scroller with JS, but you'll run into challenges as Safari sees this as positive, while Chrome (for instance) thinks it's negative, due to the `column-reverse` bit. If you come up with something, I'd be happy to update the answer!

Comment: Finally found out why this is: It's because Safari doesn't support `overflow-anchor`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-anchor#browser_compatibility

Answer (score 2):

I tried several methods and found success with the one described in this [css-tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/books/greatest-css-tricks/pin-scrolling-to-bottom/) using overflow-anchor. I'd recommend checking out the article as it has a proper explanation.

```css
#messages-container * {
  overflow-anchor: none;
}

#anchor {
  overflow-anchor: auto;
  height: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="messages-container">
  <!-- Insert messages here -->
  <div id="anchor"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scrollTop` to achieve it.

I simply wrote an example for your reference, you will find that there are two ways to implement scrollTop, one is to use the animation wrapper, the other is to use it directly, you can compare the difference between the two methods.

```js
const sendMessage = (selector, isAnimate = true) => {
  const text = $(selector).val();
  const $container = $('.form-container');
  $container.append(`<p>${text}</p>`);
  if (isAnimate) {
    $container.animate({
      scrollTop: $container.prop('scrollHeight')
    }, 1000);
  } else {
    $container.scrollTop($container.prop('scrollHeight'));
  }
  $(selector).val('');
};

$('button:eq(0)').on('click', function() {
  sendMessage('input[type=text]');
});

$('button:eq(1)').on('click', function() {
  sendMessage('input[type=text]', false);
});
```

```css
.form-container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: scroll;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<div class='form-container'>
  <p>This is line 1 of text</p>
  <p>This is line 2 of text</p>
</div>
<div>
  <input type='text' placeholder="Type a message.">
  <button type='button'>Use animation</button>
  <button type='button'>Don't use animation</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The div containing the messages: `#chat-output`

```
#chat-output {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 400px;
}
```

function `scrollToBottom()`

```
function scrollToBottom(){
    var d = $('#chat-output');
    d.scrollTop(d.prop("scrollHeight"));
}
```

Call `scrollToBottom()` every time you want the `#chat-output` to scroll to the bottom:

E.g. On DOM-ready

```
$(function () {
    scrollToBottom()
})
```

E.g after appending new chat messages to the `#chat-output`:

```
function appendNewChatItem() {
    // your append() code here
    scrollToBottom();
}
```